# WDIO - Selenium - Run Specific Test Before All Others - With Specific Capabilities

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I'm using WebDriverIO and I want to do the following:

- Run a single test before any test is run (createNewUsers)
- Use specific capabilities (proxy settings) for that first test
- Once done, use a default set of capabilities for everything else

So I can't seem to figure this out:

I've tried to add a second set of capabilities and use the `exclude` argument to ensure it only applies to that specific spec, however, I don't know whether this is actually possible and then how to call that specific test in my before block - so capabilities I use:

```
exclude: [ './newUserCreationStage/newStageUsers.js' ],
```

But then in my before block - how do I say run that (if it's possible):

```
before: function (capabilities, specs) {
    expect = require('chai').expect;

    RUN THIS './newUserCreationStage/newStageUsers.js'
},
```

Comment: `createNewUsers` doesn't sound like a test to me.

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari - Its actually a function, but I can wrap it in a describe/it block if need be

Comment: Whit TestNG you can make test dependency. Some test will be skipped if the first one fails.

Comment: @userMod2 what testing frameworks/libs do you use, besides Selenium?

Comment: @ekostadinov - WebDriverIO, Mocha and Chai

Answer (score 0):

I would say that your setup needs a bit different approach. First take a look at the xUnit [Fixture Setup Patterns](http://xunitpatterns.com/Fixture%20Setup%20Patterns.html). This `createNewUsers` can actually be achieved via SuiteFixture Setup, Prebuilt Fixture, Setup Decorator and Creation Method. This will set the [SUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_under_test) in the desired state and remove the need to

> Run a single test before any test is run

Even better - if you have access, you can seed a DB or call APIs to load all users, data and whatever you need before the test run. This is also known as [Back Door Manipulation](http://xunitpatterns.com/Back%20Door%20Manipulation.html). Let your CI server to take care of all this as a dedicated step.

Since you are using Mocha, you can [utilize tags](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Tagging) and organise your suites and specs in a better way. This will allow you to switch drivers with capabilities according to your needs (read test needs, ones may need proxy, others not). I would suggest to also consider [mocha-tags](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-tags). Good fit here is the [Strategy pattern](http://robdodson.me/javascript-design-patterns-strategy/). It will allow you to have many related subclasses which only differ in behavior.